# Zend_Db_Profiler not logging db connection time?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

Following the sample code on http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html I have set up db profiling of my Zend Framework app.

application.ini:

```
db.profiler.enabled = true
```

View Helper:

```
$totalTime    = $profiler->getTotalElapsedSecs();
$queryCount   = $profiler->getTotalNumQueries();
$longestTime  = 0;
$longestQuery = null;

foreach ($profiler->getQueryProfiles() as $query) {
    if ($query->getElapsedSecs() > $longestTime) {
        $longestTime  = $query->getElapsedSecs();
        $longestQuery = $query->getQuery();
    }
}

echo 'Executed ' . $queryCount . ' queries in ' . $totalTime . ' seconds' . "\n";
echo 'Average query length: ' . $totalTime / $queryCount . ' seconds' . "\n";
echo 'Queries per second: ' . $queryCount / $totalTime . "\n";
echo 'Longest query length: ' . $longestTime . "\n";
echo "Longest query: \n" . $longestQuery . "\n";
```

It works fine for select/insert/update/delete queries.

But I cannot find anyway to get the profiler to show the time taken to initiate the actual db connection, despite the documenation implying that it does log this.

I suspect that Zend_Db simply does not log the connection to the db with the profiler.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

I am using the Oracle database adapter, and ZF 1.10.1

***UPDATE:***

I understand it is possible to filter the profiler output, such that it will only show certain query types, e.g. select/insert/update. There also appears to be an option to filter just the connection records:

```
$profiler->setFilterQueryType(Zend_Db_Profiler::CONNECT);
```

However, my problem is that the profiler is **not logging the connections to begin with**, so this filter does nothing.

I know this for a fact, because if I print the profiler object, it contains data for many different queries - but no data for the connection queries:

```
print_r($profiler);
```

```
//output
Zend_Db_Profiler Object
(
    [_queryProfiles:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Zend_Db_Profiler_Query Object
                (
                    [_query:protected] => select * from table1
                    [_queryType:protected] => 32
                    [_startedMicrotime:protected] => 1268104035.3465
                    [_endedMicrotime:protected] => 1268104035.3855
                    [_boundParams:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Zend_Db_Profiler_Query Object
                (
                    [_query:protected] => select * from table2
                    [_queryType:protected] => 32
                    [_startedMicrotime:protected] => 1268104035.3882
                    [_endedMicrotime:protected] => 1268104035.419
                    [_boundParams:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [_enabled:protected] => 1
    [_filterElapsedSecs:protected] => 
    [_filterTypes:protected] => 
)
```

Am I doing something wrong - or has logging of connections just not been added to Zend Framework yet?

Answer (score 0):

The profiler 'bundles' connection and other operations in with the general queries.

There's three ways you might examine the connection specifically:

1. Set a filter on the profiler during setup:

   > ```
   > $profiler->setFilterQueryType(**Zend_Db_Profiler::CONNECT**);
   > ```

   Then the resultant profiles will only include 'connect' operations.
2. Specify a query type when you retrieve the Query Profiles:

   > ```
   > $profiles = $profiler->getQueryProfiles(**Zend_Db_Profiler::CONNECT**);
   > ```
3. Examine the query objects directly during the iteration:

   > ```
   > foreach($profiler->getQueryProfiles() as $query) {
   > if ($query->getQueryType() == Zend_Db_Profiler::CONNECT &&
   >    $query->getElapsedSecs() > $longestConnectionTime) {
   >        $longestConnectionTime  = $query->getElapsedSecs();
   >    } 
   > }
   > ```

You'll not find great detail in there, it's logged just as a 'connect' operation along with the time taken.

Comment: That's my problem though - this isn't working for me! There are no connection records logged, so there is nothing to filter. I'll try and update my question to give more information on this.

Comment: It does seem that the Oracle adapter is not making the relevant calls to the profiler for connection. Comparing the _connect() methods in Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract and Zend_Db_Adapter_Oracle, before creating the connection the former calls:

  $q = $this->_profiler->queryStart('connect', Zend_Db_Profiler::CONNECT); 

and afterwards:

  $this->_profiler->queryEnd($q);

The Oracle adapter has no reference to the profiler (up to version 1.10.2 at least), but I imagine it might be as simple as adding equivalent calls in the _connect() method.